# Editing the ribbon button URL

Tags: ribbon

I would like to edit the the link that the close button on the ribbon redirects users to. Is this possible and how do I go about doing so?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Emma, Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange, I would like to start off by recommending you read the [FAQ][1] for posting as while your question is clear it opens up multiple answers depending on why and how you want it to act. Therefore we recommend that you always provide the scenario as well as the question and if possible an example.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a custom control on the ribbon**

The following MSDN article describes how to create custom controls, this is the best solution for future proofing your fix. This is because if you update your SharePoint other fixes such as replacing the link with JQuery may break.

[**Walkthrough: Replacing a Button on the Server Ribbon**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407619%28v=office.14%29.aspx)